# Using Fundamental Theorem of calculus with piecewise function

Tags: calculus

The question I'm trying to solve is as follows:

Suppose $h(x)$ is a piecewise defined function with

$$h(x) = \begin{cases} 2x+4 & x \in [-2,-1) \\ -2x & x \in [-1,1] \\ 2x-4 & x \in (1,3] \end{cases}$$

Let

$$g(x)=\int_{-2}^xh(t)dt$$

On what interval(s) is $g$ increasing?

$(-2, 0)$ and $(2, 3)$

$(-1, 1)$

$(-2, -1)$ and $(1, 3)$

$(-2, 3)$

I know I have to use the fundamental theorem of calculus to solve but I'm seriously stuck and it would be awesome if someone could explain to me how to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry about the horrible question formatting. I'm still pretty new to this and I get a little confused about the coding stuff. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a differentiable function is increasing on an interval iff its derivative is positive on that interval. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $g'(x) = h(x)$. So for what values of $x$ is $h(x)$ above the $x$-axis?

Comment: Minor point: A differentiable function can be increasing on an interval if its derivative is zero at a finite number of points in the interval (and positive elsewhere). For instance, $f(x) = x^3$ is increasing on all of $(-\infty,\infty)$ even though $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Okay so I tried it out and I found that $g(x)$ is increasing on the intervals $(-2,-1)\bigcup(1,3)$ . But it's telling me that my answer is wrong so could you please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Notice that $h(-0.5) = -2(-0.5) = 1 > 0$ so the answer should include $-0.5$. Furthermore, notice that $h(1.5) = 2(1.5) - 4 = -1 < 0$, so the answer should NOT include $1.5$. Have you tried sketching a graph of $h(x)$?

Comment: I actually just sketched a graph and found that answer should be $(-2,0)\bigcup(2,3)$. Now I'm trying to figure out $g(3)$. I figured that I would use $\int2x-4dx$ and then I could just plug $3$ in for $x$ but the answer I got was also wrong.

Comment: You'll need to integrate each section separately, then add them up:
$$
\int_{-2}^{-1}(2x + 4) \, dx + \int_{-1}^1 (-2x)\,dx + \int_1^3 (2x - 4) \, dx
$$
Or just use your graph of $h(x)$ and add up the areas of the triangles above the $x$-axis and subtract the areas of the triangles below the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

FTC tells you $g$ is differentiable and that $g'(x) = h(x)$.

In general, a differentiable function is increasing when the derivative is positive.

If you put those together, the question is equivalent to "On what interval(s) is $h$ positive?"